# Domain, Hosting and DNS management on 3 seperate providers - is this possible?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, dns, godaddy

***I wanted to know if its possible to do the following:***

1. Buy Domain from GoDaddy.
2. Buy Hosting from HostGator.
3. Buy DNS Management from DNS Made Easy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. If you look at this article on the Godaddy website:
http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/664/setting-nameservers-for-your-domain-names
and look at the section "Setting Nameservers for a Domain Name Registered Elsewhere and Using Off-site DNS" it will tell you how to set up the DNS. Then you need to configure the DNS to point to your hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! It is possible to register a domain name from Godaddy, purchase a hosting package from hostgator and use the DNS management from a different company.

It is advisable to use the DNS management service provided by your hosting company itself; Hostgator in this case.